# Calculate Disk Latency During A Write C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a random file using this code

```
  using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                {
                    // There 
                    for (int i = 0; i < counti++)
                    {
                        rng.NextBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);              
                    }
                }
```

during this write I want to record the average disk latency time. Are there metrics for this that you can do a calculation off of in a win32 call?

```
   ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
              new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
              "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk");
```

I am not seeing much on this topic out there

Comment: A write does not, by default, imply a flush: buffers are wonderful things, but can also hide the actual underlying operations. Trying to gather such timings from within .NET - as opposed to a more bare-metal approach - probably doesn't help either, although since the question is focused on WMI.. In any case, it might be useful to look at the implementations of the various open-sourced HD benchmark programs.

Comment: Great, question is already asked. How about, you call stream.flush after you write your bytes and use the stopwatch class to benchmark how long it took to complete?